# Sending data from html.index to functions.js file

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I am stuck on working with a .html file which needs to send over data to a javascript file with functions. It looks as follows:

Data

```
let data = [
    ["ID1", "URL1"],
    ["ID2", "URL2"],
    ["ID3", "URL3"],
]
```

HTML part calling javascript functions file with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Metabase Dashboard Carousel</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/carousel.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="createFrames('test!')">
    <button class="btn btn-primary " onclick=autoRun()>Start</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary " onclick=pause()>Pause</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Function which is called

```
function createFrames(text) {
    console.log(text);
    for(var i in data)        
        prepareFrame(data[i][0], data[i][1]);
};
```

Calling the function does give me a print of test! on the .html console with Mozilla inspector. However, running the rest of the script or actually using the data variable as input in the body onLoad function does not work.

1. How does this come and what would be a fix?
2. Also, not directly related what is a good way to load files between related .js / .yml / .json as when running the code in .html gives back that require is not defined?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `prepareFrameSources`? What is `prepareFrame`? Defining `let data` both inside and outside the function - which one will take precedence?

Comment: prepareFrame is the function that adds dynamically <iframes> to the body of the html document. 

Let data has been wrongly defined in the function, it should take the data variable as defined at the start of my question.

Comment: And is the problem that the `createFrames` function is NOT correctly processing the declared `data` variable when the page loads? Also - where is this variable defined? Is it within `carousel.js`?

Comment: The problem is that instead of passing createFrames('test!') onLoad in the body I would like to have something as:

<body onLoad="createFrames(data)">

Where data is the list as defined at the start of this discussion. 

I tried adding data directly on the load within the script tags, but it does not seem to work. Specifically, I would not like to have the data variable in carousel.js.

Comment: so where is this variable defined? Do you intend to define it directly as a argument of the function? Are you able to adopt a different strategy other than `<body onload="func(data)">` etc???

Comment: Hi, yes I am able to adopt a different strategy but I am not aware of best practice to handle this. 

In essence I want to send the data over from the .html file to the .js file and cannot proceed further atm... Ideally it would be done via the onLoad function and using a variable there but if you know other routes please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to modify your approach and are wanting to define the runtime data that will be used by the `onload` function you might try an approach like this. This uses an anonymous self executing function to run the `prepareFrame` commands once the DOM has been fully loaded. The data is supplied as an argument to the anonymous function and other functions can be defined within this scope so as to keep the whole thing neat.

```js
(function(data){
  const d=document;
  
  // emulate actual functions with simple console cmds for testing only
  const prepareFrame=(a,b)=>{
    console.log('prepareFrame(%s,%s)',a,b)
  };
  const autoRun=(e)=>{console.log(e.target);return true};
  const pause=(e)=>{console.log(e.target);return true}


  d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
     data.forEach(a=>{
      prepareFrame(a[0],a[1])
     });

     d.querySelectorAll('button[data-task]').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      switch(this.dataset.task){
        case 'start':return autoRun(e);
        case 'pause':return pause(e);
      }
     }))
  })  
})([
  ["ID1", "URL1"],
  ["ID2", "URL2"],
  ["ID3", "URL3"],
]);
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-primary' data-task='start'>Start</button>
<button class='btn btn-primary' data-task='pause'>Pause</button>
```

For instance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html;charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    <meta content='utf-8' http-equiv='encoding' />
    
    <title>Metabase Dashboard Carousel</title>
    <link href='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We' crossorigin='anonymous' />
    
    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='./src/carousel.js'></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' data-task='start'>Start</button>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' data-task='pause'>Pause</button>
  </body>
  
  <script>
    (function(data){
      const d=document;
      
      // emulate actual functions with simple console cmds for testing only
      const prepareFrame=(a,b)=>{
        console.log('prepareFrame(%s,%s)',a,b)
      };
      const autoRun=(e)=>{console.log(e.target);return true};
      const pause=(e)=>{console.log(e.target);return true}


      d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
         data.forEach(a=>{
          prepareFrame(a[0],a[1])
         });

         d.querySelectorAll('button[data-task]').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
          switch(this.dataset.task){
            case 'start':return autoRun(e);
            case 'pause':return pause(e);
          }
         }))
      })  
    })([
      ["ID1", "URL1"],
      ["ID2", "URL2"],
      ["ID3", "URL3"],
    ]);
  </script>
</html>
```